# What will happen if electron as a wave undergo destructive interference while travelling in its Orbit?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, atomic-radius, atomic-structure

Today I came across a justification of Bohr's angular momentum quantization using the De- Broglie's hypothesis.

The justification said that since the electrons are having wave nature also then while travelling in its Orbit there is starting point and ending point must concide in order to avoid destructive interference of wave.

**What will happen if electron as a wave undergo destructive interference while travelling in its Orbit ?**

If the electron goes under constructive interference then it's amplitude should increase each time. Is it possible ??

Comment: It is not possible. That was just a simplistic rationalization of the quantization assumed by Bohr. So no worries!

Comment: I am not sure how De Broglie might have come to this conclusion at that time (if indeed he did, I have not read his work), but another interpretation would be that a discontinuity would be inconsistent with a time-independent (stationary) state such as Bohr was postulating.

Comment: @Tushar — The thing is that waves are constrained by length/radius... so they are standing waves. In other words, all the wavelengths which are not proportional to the length/radius cancel out (and only standing waves survive)! One way or another, you only get standing waves which, by definition, don't cancel out